# Google Tag Manager wont fire if I click on the Copy / Text of the Button

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-tag-manager, elementor

My google tag manager wont fire when I click on the copy of the CTA Button. But it fires when I click the CTA Button area around the copy.

[If I click "Talk to us now", GTM wont fire. But if I click the orange area, GTM will fire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuFQ1.png)

GTM Trigger: Click All Elements - Click URL - Equals - https://annotationlabs.com/contact-us/
I

I am using Elementor to edit my wordpress website if that helps. Not sure what the error is.

My Website Code is below:

```
<a href="https://annotationlabs.com/contact-us/" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-sm elementor-animation-bob" role="button">
<span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
<span class="elementor-button-icon elementor-align-icon-right">
<i aria-hidden="true" class=" stm-right-arrow"></i> </span>
<span class="elementor-button-text">Talk to us now</span>
</span>
</a>
```

Additionally "_event" comes as "gtm.js" which isnt same as "gtm.click"

[image]
[image]

Will be really helpful if someone can help me with the fix?

Comment: Did you figure it out?